# How to put into HTML code that will load data from another server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asynchronous, jsonp

I am interested in the functionality of Disqus - a user will put code from Disqus and this code will remotely fetch the data necessary. Here's an example of what Disqus provides the user:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var disqus_shortname = 'domainname';
  (function() {
     var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
     dsq.src = 'http://' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
     (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
   })();
</script>
```

I am unfortunately unfamiliar with this concept: I have read that this technique uses asynchronous javascript and JSONP, but could you give me a basic example of how can I make this work with something similar? For example, how can I load data this way from a remote database and display them into user's page?

Comment: I found this one really clear and useful when I was in your case. http://iviewsource.com/codingtutorials/getting-started-with-javascript-object-notation-json-for-absolute-beginners/

Answer (score 2):

The technique as you correctly state is from the [XHR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) family. Often people also use the terminology [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) without realizing the real meaning behind it. People tend to utilize XHR without XML often relying on other data exchange formats (think container) such as [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) or [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). The container format is quite different from the technique used to actually callback to the server. Recently since HTML5 also the [PushState](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax) method has become widely popular. For beginners I would suggest jumping into the cold water directly with PJAX as it is the most recent development and rather widely [supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=pushstate). Here is a working example for [PJAX](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax/tree/heroku/app). Otherwise if you like to rely on full client side only via e.g. jQuery you can do that [too](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp).

These days more and more popular are client side MVC or templating engines which consume JSON and render directly on the client. One popular framework for this is e.g. [EmberJS](http://emberjs.com/).
A more rudimentary approach trying to separate logic and markup which consumes JSON is e.g. [Mustache](http://mustache.github.io/).

Here is a [very basic example](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_load) with pure JavaScript you can fiddle around.

Comment: +1 for typing up and expounding on something like I was going to say :)